# Show an object right after hidding another with ng-show/ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make the effect when a button is clicked, the button fades out and in the same place a load animation fades in, but I can't manage to make the load animation show after the button is totally hidden.

In the HTML I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <button ng-hide="login.sendingAjax" type="submit" id="loginButton" class="form-control btn btn-primary uppercase">INGRESAR</button>
   <loader ng-if="login.sendingAjax" ng-show="login.sendingAjax" class="loaderContainer"></loader>
</div>
```

Then in my controller I have the function when the form is being submited, in that moment I put the login.sendingAjax variable to true for the button to be hidden and the animation to appear, and when it ends the call with a failure I put the login.sendingAjax variable back to false:

```
    vm.loginError = false;
    vm.sendingAjax = false;

    /**
     * Submit the form and check if login was ok
     */
    vm.loginUser = function() {
      vm.loginError = false;
      vm.sendingAjax = true;
      vm.alert = {};

      authService.login(vm.formData).then(function () {
        $location.path('/ubicaciones');
      },
      function () {
        vm.alert = {type: 'danger', msg: 'Hola'};
        vm.sendingAjax = false;
        vm.loginError = true;
      });
    };
```

The CSS is:

```
.ng-hide-add         { animation:0.5s hideObjectOpacity ease; }

/* when showing the picture */
.ng-hide-remove      { animation:0.5s flipInX ease; }

/* ANIMATIONS (FROM ANIMATE.CSS) ======================== */
/* flip in */
@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

/* light speed out */
@keyframes hideObjectOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: create a demo that replicates this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways to handle that. one is that while NOT using `ng-hide` and `ng-show`, you can do the fade out animation with a function inside your JS (using a module like VelocityJS or ...), and inside it's callback, fade in the other element (the element should be `display:none` by default, and the animations should change the display property in their progress).

or you have to use different toggles for the `ng-hide` and `ng-show`, and set the `ng-show` toggle to `true` in the first function's callback or using `$timeout` ...

you can also fake the delay in entrance by manipulating the first few steps of the css animation and say set the `opacity` to `0` in them, until the first element is completely out... but i don't think it's a proper way of doing it . (considering your layout might change because an element with `opacity:0` still exists in there!)

tell me if you need an example to understand it better

Comment: Thanks, I went with the different toggles approach